# Relay Denied SMTP error from remote mail server after RCPT TO: <email@example.com>

Tags: ubuntu, email, email-server, exim, gmail

Hi I have a problem when I want to send mail using smarthost method in exim and usage Mailgun as SMTP server for relay.

this is my configuration

```
dc_eximconfig_configtype='smarthost'
dc_other_hostnames='example.com'
dc_local_interfaces='127.0.0.1 ; ::1'
dc_readhost=''
dc_relay_domains='*'
dc_minimaldns='false'
dc_relay_nets='my_network_ip.0/24'
dc_smarthost='smtp.mailgun.org:587'
CFILEMODE='644'
dc_use_split_config='false'
dc_hide_mailname='false'
dc_mailname_in_oh='true'
dc_localdelivery='mail_spool'
```

then when I am try to send mail and look up in logs I have this result

```
2015-03-18 12:04:09 1YYChl-0002iS-14 <= admin@example.com H=localhost (admin@example.com) [127.0.0.1] P=esmtp S=752 id=84a9b3b278174ec2d634bfed7c42bac9.squirrel@localhost
2015-03-18 12:04:10 1YYChl-0002iS-14 ** test@mail.co.id R=smarthost T=remote_smtp_smarthost: SMTP error from remote mail server after RCPT TO:<test@mail.co.id>: host smtp.mailgun.org [50.56.21.178]: 550 5.7.1 Relaying denied
2015-03-18 12:04:10 1YYChm-0002ia-1K <= <> R=1YYChl-0002iS-14 U=Debian-exim P=local S=1690
2015-03-18 12:04:10 1YYChl-0002iS-14 Completed
2015-03-18 12:04:10 1YYChm-0002ia-1K => admin <admin@example.com> R=vmail_deliver T=vmail_delivery
2015-03-18 12:04:10 1YYChm-0002ia-1K Completed
```

someone can help me to fix this ?

Comment: Well, this is totally expected behavior. You are imitating the manner of spammers here. I guess you want to authenticate at mailgun first, to prove you are a customer of them.

Comment: can you give me more details information for fix this ?

Comment: [WP: SMTP Authentication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SMTP_Authentication) and [Authentication by an exim client](http://www.exim.org/exim-html-current/doc/html/spec_html/ch-smtp_authentication.html#SECID170)

Answer (score 2):

[This page](https://documentation.mailgun.com/user_manual.html#smtp-relay) explains how to config exim with mailgun. You need setup relay host and SMTP auth to let mailgun accept your email.

In `exim.conf` and routes configuration:

```
# In routes configuration
mailgun:
        driver = manualroute
        domains = ! +local_domains
        transport = mailgun_transport
        route_list = * smtp.mailgun.org byname

# In transports configuration:
    mailgun_transport:
    driver=smtp
    hosts_try_auth = smtp.mailgun.org
```

Also make sure to configure login credentials (in your /etc/exim/passwd.client):

```
*.mailgun.org:username:password
```